# Do Githyanki lay eggs in 5E?

Tags: dnd-5e, monsters, lore, gith

The chapter "Citadel of Gith Reborn" from the 2nd edition adventure book [*Vortex of Madness*](https://www.dmsguild.com/product/17282/The-Vortex-of-Madness-and-other-Planer-Perils-2e) says that Githyanki lay eggs despite being humanoid.

The 5e [*Monster Manual* entry for Githyanki](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mm/monsters-g#Gith) doesn't say much about their methods of reproduction. Is there any 5e material that addresses this issue?

Comment: Now related: [Do Githzerai hatch from eggs in 5e](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/171624)

Answer (score 39):

## They do

*Mordenkainen's Tome of Foes* dedicates its [fourth chapter](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mtof/gith-and-their-endless-war) (starting at p. 85) to the gith, expanding upon the material found in the *Monster Manual*. On page 87, under the heading ["Only the Best Survive"](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/mtof/gith-and-their-endless-war#OnlytheBestSurvive), it has the line:

> Githyanki hatch from eggs.

Which is a fairly clear answer.

Comment: I know it's weird, but this is *D&D*: Does *Tome of Foes* make it clear that githyanki hatch from eggs that the githyanki themselves lay?

Comment: @HeyICanChan Now that you point it out, no it doesn't. Though, if there were some other source of these eggs I feel like *that* would have been mentioned.

Comment: Cool. That could make an interesting plot: A band of rebel githyanki travels the planes in search of the egg of a god so that they can use it to breed a super-githyanki or something. (*Rebel githyanki* because certainly the lich-queen would *not* approve!) Or—even more extreme (and silly)—any ol' egg the players find—pigeon, viper, owlbear—could hatch and, instead of the expected result, yield a githyanki. Good times.